# Is there any MySQL String Function which will add two or more strings in one string and can display new string starting with last string?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Right now I know how to use CONCAT basically.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(Michael, ' ', 'Jordan')";
```

Using a line of this code I get the result: Michael Jordan.

I want to get all strings in one string like this: Jordan Michael.

Below is my original code which I using for search users.

```
"SELECT `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`, 
        `follow_user`.`idFollower`,
        `follow_user`.`idFollowed`, 
        `users`.`idUsers`, 
        `users`.`nameUsers`, 
        `users`.`surnameUsers`, 
        `users`.`pictureUsers`, 
        `users`.`pictureUsersType`, 
        `users`.`folderUsers` 
 FROM `follow_user` 
        LEFT JOIN `users` ON `follow_user`.`idFollowed`=`users`.`idUsers` 
 WHERE `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`<=? 
    AND `follow_user`.`idFollower`=? 
    AND (CONCAT(`users`.`nameUsers`, ' ', `users`.`surnameUsers`) LIKE ?) 
 ORDER BY CAST(`follow_user`.`follow_user_id` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
```

In my SQL table `users` my first column is `nameUsers` and secound `surnameUsers`. When I searching users typing firstly name SPACE surname than I have result.

Problem is when I typing firstly surname SPACE name I do not have any result.

Example when typing:
Michael Jordan - I have displayed result,
but when Jordan Michael - I do not have any result.

I has trying:

```
(CONCAT(`users`.`surnameUsers`, ' ', `users`.`nameUsers`) LIKE ?)
```

and:

```
(CONCAT(`users`.`surnameUsers`, ' ', `users`.`nameUsers`) REGEXP ?)
```

but no results again, so by me its mean MySQL String Function CONCAT() can only read and add two or more strings in one new string only sequentially from first string from SQL table column.

I need the user may enter name and surname in any order.

Comment: "two or more strings in one string" does mean...what ?

Comment: What's wrong with `CONCAT( 'Jordan', ' ', 'Michael')` ?

Comment: If the goal is to have LastName, FirstName, Middle, why not define the `CONCAT()` like that? "Fuzzy" logic often results in "fuzzy bugs" ...

Comment: Define your own stored function (CREATE FUNCTION) which accepts the parameters in some order and CONCATs them with another parameters order.

Comment: Assuming your actual scenario is more complicated that this and you have a number of columns that you need to concatenate and order alphabetically, then you could basically unpivot your columns to rows, then concatenate using `GROUP_CONCAT` which allows you to specify an order, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=865caf0a901f105d3dbcc66f66e71d3f Your requirements aren't very clear though, so I have no idea if that is what you actually want to do (hence the comment rather than an answer)

Comment: @Akina `$sql_3 = "SELECT `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`, `follow_user`.`idFollower`, `follow_user`.`idFollowed`, `users`.`idUsers`, `users`.`nameUsers`, `users`.`surnameUsers`, `users`.`pictureUsers`, `users`.`pictureUsersType`, `users`.`folderUsers` FROM `follow_user` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `follow_user`.`idFollowed`=`users`.`idUsers` WHERE `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`<=? AND `follow_user`.`idFollower`=? AND (CONCAT(`users`.`nameUsers`, ' ', `users`.`surnameUsers`) REGEXP ?) ORDER BY CAST(`follow_user`.`follow_user_id` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT ?, ?";`

Comment: @Akina above is my original code. I using it in my users searching machine. I have problem because when I searching users starts from name `space` surname everithing is fine, but when I starts search users starts from surname `space` name no results found.

Comment: Why you cannot simply swap columns in your SQL?

Comment: @Akina if I will swap columns in my SQL i will have problem with searching users starts from name `space` surname. I want to have two options warking.

Comment: @The Impaler that code works correct. I using that code and I want to use. I looking foor something simmilar to My SQL string Function CONCAT() but to read strings from back of table and add them to one string. My SQL string Function CONCAT() gives me only one option to read strings from start of table and add them to one string but that new string starts from first column. I need to have new string which will starts from last column `surnameUsers`.

Comment: Please provide a couple of rows of sample data and the expected result (simple example, please).

Comment: @The Impaler in my previously answer to Akina above I provide already some lines of my code. Did you seen that?

Comment: @GarethD above in one of my comments I pasted some lines of my original code and later I tryied explain what I looking for. Thanks for your comment, Its very interesting and link too.

Comment: @Grzes Rather than paste code in comments, it is better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68833281/edit) as it is much easier to read. In addition the SQL, some sample data and expected output would be really useful to fully understand the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the user may enter name and surname in any order, and you want the row to be found in both cases? If so then parse user's input to separate words, check for them separately, and ensure that both checks are successful. Or backward, check the columns values joined in both variants and ensure that some of these checks is successful.

Comment: you could change the regexp parameter: what are you using as regexp comparation param?

Comment: @Ivan Buttioni so in my case I should using `LIKE` than `REGEXP`? I will swap `REGEXP` with `LIKE` and come back with the result.

Comment: You can check 'Jordan Michael' or the output from `concat(substring_index('Jordan Michael',' ',-1),' ',substring_index('Jordan Michael',' ',1))`....

Answer (score 1):

It seem to me that your goal is to find all the records that matches an user-input on different columns using `regexp`, and the focus (of this answer) should be how you search the pattern.

**REGEXP APPROACH**

Here two examples with user-input as "Jordan" but with different regexp modifiers:

```
SELECT '^Jordan' as search, CONCAT('Michael', ' ', 'Jordan') regexp '^Jordan' as found;
```

| search | found |
| --- | --- |
| ^Jordan | 0 |

```
SELECT '.*Jordan.*' as search, CONCAT('Michael', ' ', 'Jordan') regexp '.*Jordan.*' as found;
```

| search | found |
| --- | --- |
| .*Jordan.* | 1 |

- see [mysql regexp documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)
- see [regexp online tester](https://extendsclass.com/regex/33ba46d)

**LIKE APPROACH**

```
SELECT '%Jordan%' as search, CONCAT('Michael', ' ', 'Jordan') like '%Jordan%' as found;
```

| search | found |
| --- | --- |
| %Jordan% | 1 |

**FULL TEXT SEARCH APPROACH**

By create a Full text index:

```
create fulltext index index_name on users (nameUsers, surnameUsers);
```

Will work with "*michael jordan*":

```
SELECT `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollower`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollowed`,
       `users`.`idUsers`,
       `users`.`nameUsers`,
       `users`.`surnameUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsersType`,
       `users`.`folderUsers`
FROM `follow_user`
       LEFT JOIN `users` ON `follow_user`.`idFollowed` = `users`.`idUsers`
WHERE `follow_user`.`follow_user_id` <= ?
  AND `follow_user`.`idFollower` = ?
  AND (MATCH (nameUsers, surnameUsers) AGAINST ('michael jordan' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE))
ORDER BY CAST(`follow_user`.`follow_user_id` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
LIMIT 1, 100;
```

and with "*jordan michael*" too:

```
SELECT `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollower`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollowed`,
       `users`.`idUsers`,
       `users`.`nameUsers`,
       `users`.`surnameUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsersType`,
       `users`.`folderUsers`
FROM `follow_user`
       LEFT JOIN `users` ON `follow_user`.`idFollowed` = `users`.`idUsers`
WHERE `follow_user`.`follow_user_id` <= ?
  AND `follow_user`.`idFollower` = ?
  AND (MATCH (nameUsers, surnameUsers) AGAINST ('jordan michael' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE))
ORDER BY CAST(`follow_user`.`follow_user_id` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
LIMIT 1, 100;
```

**FULL TEXT SEARCH APPROACH - ADVANCED**

Full text search can use "*"

```
SELECT `follow_user`.`follow_user_id`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollower`,
       `follow_user`.`idFollowed`,
       `users`.`idUsers`,
       `users`.`nameUsers`,
       `users`.`surnameUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsers`,
       `users`.`pictureUsersType`,
       `users`.`folderUsers`
FROM `follow_user`
       LEFT JOIN `users` ON `follow_user`.`idFollowed` = `users`.`idUsers`
WHERE `follow_user`.`follow_user_id` <= ?
  AND `follow_user`.`idFollower` = ?
  AND (MATCH (nameUsers, surnameUsers) AGAINST ('jordan mich*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
ORDER BY CAST(`follow_user`.`follow_user_id` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
LIMIT 1, 100;
```

To achieve your **boolean search** you can *clean* you input string with the following code:

```
$searchString=implode(" ",array_filter(explode(" ",$inputString."*"),function ($e){return !($e=="" || $e=="*");}));
```

Here the table input/search

| inputString | searchString |
| --- | --- |
| m | m* |
| michael | michael* |
| michael SPACE | michael |
| michael SPACE j | michael j* |
| michael SPACE jordan | michael jordan* |
| michael SPACE jordan SPACE | michael jordan |

- see [Full text search documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)
- see also [Full text search in boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for an *advanced* search

Comment: MATCH() function searches works great but it doesn't give me the result I want. It works differently from `REGEXP` and` LIKE`. `MATCH () function` only displays the result when I type a whole word, for example` Michael`. `REGEXP` and` LIKE` displays the result after typing the first letter, for example `M`, I need auto-complete from the first letter I entered. `Please go to next message below. This is message 1 of 2`.

Comment: An additional disadvantage for me of the `MATCH ()` function is that if I type a whole word and get the result from all columns for which I `create fulltext index`, the next word I type does not change the result. The result remains the same even if the second and next words do not exist in any of the columns. Your solutions are very interesting, Thank you. `This is message 2 of 2`.

Comment: and this is my code `SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(nameUsers, surnameUsers, bioUsers) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY CAST(idUsers AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 5`. Above are two messages relating to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply have an `OR` condition so it matches either of the ways you search

```
(AND (CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers) REGEXP ?
 OR (CONCAT(users.surnameUsers, ' ', users.nameUsers) REGEXP ?)
```

If your `REGEXP` is wildcarded on both sides and you are okay with the possibility of getting more than one result for the same `REGEXP` due to fuzzy match, you could also do

```
AND (CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers, ' ', users.nameUsers)  REGEXP ?
```

Comment: I just minute ago again just swap my original line `(CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers)` for `(CONCAT(users.surnameUsers, ' ', users.nameUsers)` and after that when I typing name with surname in any order I do not have any results, and after that swap I have only results when typing name or surname but separately. I thought I could add a copy of the first name column after the last name column, but in the SQL table it is impossible :-p. Column names cannot be repeated in SQL :-(.

Comment: @Grzes What do you mean by "Column names cannot be repeated in SQL"?

Comment: I mean Columns names in a same table SQL can not be repeated. If some one would like to create new column named for example `nameUsers` in same SQL table then it will be not possible because names of the columns in the same SQL table must be unique. In the end will be error message: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'nameUsers'. Sorry I should have been more specific with my writing.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your implementation. Are you searching for specific users? Are you creating tables? Why would repeating columns in the where clause have anything to do with creating tables?

Comment: I swap line `(CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers) REGEXP ?)` for `(CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers, ' ', users.nameUsers) REGEXP ?)` and after test I have result when I typing name SPACE surname user but I do not have result when I typing surname SPACE name user. When I typing separately name or surname I have result.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=78b8d239161af5e1d5c0b569295adf2c

Try using the OR condition like above in my answer

Comment: I swap `(CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers) REGEXP ?)` for `((CONCAT(nameUsers, ' ', surnameUsers) REGEXP ?) OR (CONCAT(surnameUsers, ' ', nameUsers) REGEXP ?))`  and when I typing name with surname in any order no results. I have results only when typing seperetly name or surname. Later I swap in my orgiginal code that line only `(CONCAT(users.nameUsers, ' ', users.surnameUsers) REGEXP ?)` for `(CONCAT(users.surnameUsers, ' ', users`.`nameUsers) REGEXP ?)` just for check only that option, and no results when I typing firtly surname SPACE name.

Comment: @Grzes Is the search parameter automatically trimming spaces? Is if so , you might want to handle that before matching. To test if that's true use hyphen (-) instead of spaces

Comment: I insert in empty string ' ' a sting '-'.  Now my code looks: `((CONCAT(nameUsers, '-', surnameUsers) REGEXP ?) OR (CONCAT(surnameUsers, '-', nameUsers) REGEXP ?))`. When I typing `Michael-` or typing `Michael-Jordan` or `-Jordan` I have results but when somewere is SPACE I do not have results. `Jordan-` no results too. Please go to next message below this is 1 of 2.

Comment: When in my original code is only one CONCAT `(CONCAT(users.surnameUsers, '-', users.nameUsers) REGEXP ?)` when I typing`Michael` or `Jordan` seperetly I have result, but when I typing `Michael-` or `-Jordan` or `Michael-Jordan` or `Jordan-` I do not have results. When I do SPACE before or after `Michael` or `Jordan` I do not have results after swap empty string for `-` string. Message 2 of 2.

Comment: I suspect your names and surnames may have leading or trailing spaces. Try trimming them before concatenating them with spaces

Comment: Do you mean that I should use trim()? I was using trim()before in that line: `$fullNameUsers = filter_var(trim($_POST['users_search_s']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` and I was trying without trim() too and after all tests is same problem. In my SQL table rows all names and surnames are without spaces.

Comment: At this point, I don’t think it’s a SQL problem. See if you can output some sample data to a text file to make sure names and surnames appear as they should

Comment: for now I am know that line `if ($result_3->num_rows > 0) {` stops displaying data from SQL when I typing surname SPACE name user.